# umbraco 7.0.4 bundling not working

Tags: umbraco, bundling-and-minification, umbraco7

I'm trying to use the Bundling and Minification feature on a Umbraco 7.0.4. I'm getting a 404 error. I've manually added my virtual prefix path in web.config ("umbracoReservedPaths" variable) but it still not working.

I also added the version 1.1.0 of Web.Optimization nuget running the command:

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization -Version 1.1.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the Global.asax Application_Start is not executed. I had to use WebActivator to "simulate" this bevahior. In there, I call BundleConfig.RegisterBundles() and it works.